# How to get next id in a kendo grid when click on update button on the grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid in which the data is bind on the basis of some conditions. The grid has a column named "Request ids". The column displays the list of random request ids. There is also a update button on the grid.

I pass the request id to the controller through jquery. I get the id for the selected case by:

```
var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
```

So the dataItem.ServiceRequestID gives me the id.
But, here I also want the next Request id displayed in the grid.

Can any one help me how to get the next id in the grid?

Also consider the scenario if only ten item is displayed on the screen then how will we get the id of 11th item.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var nextDataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr").next("tr"));
```

Comment: Thanks it worked....... Actually i tried this also but in the quick watch window and it was displayed as undefined. Thanks...

Comment: For if i am displaying ten records in a grid then how to get the id of 11th record. As for that it is showing undefined.